# Including the 'required' attribute in this jQuery

Tags: jquery, required

This is building an input in a jQuery file:

```
_buildScoreField: function() {
    return $('<input />' , {
        name: this.opt.scoreName,
        type: 'hidden'
    }).appendTo(this);
},
```

I'm try to add the `required` attribute to this `input` element, but I've never seen it formatted this way so I'm unsure how to do so.

Comment: Its being used for a star rating

Answer (score 0):

It's using [this variant of `$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes), which allows you to give attributes, properties, and even some methods in an object as the second argument. Add `required: true` to that object (`required: "required"` would also work, but jQuery understands that `required` is a boolean reflected property as well as attribute and handles that correctly for you):

```
_buildScoreField: function() {
    return $('<input />' , {
       name: this.opt.scoreName,
       type: 'hidden',
       required: true // <====
    }).appendTo(this);
}
```

That said, making a hidden input `required` seems....odd. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`{ name: this.opt.scoreName  , type: 'hidden' }` is the attributes for the element being created. Pass a key value pair as an additional option.

```
{ name: this.opt.scoreName  , type: 'hidden', required: true }
```

More documentation is found here..

```
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an `input` element of type 'hidden' required. From the [MDN `<input>` spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required):

> **required** 
>   This attribute specifies that the user must fill in a value before submitting a form. It cannot be used when the type attribute is hidden, image, or a button type (submit, reset, or button).

Consider what use-case you're trying to solve, and use the appropriate `input` types, and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking to add an attribute `required="required"`, use the following attribute/value pair in your constructor:

```
required: 'required'
```

Adding the attribute with a zero-length value is valid too: `required: ''`

```
$('<input />' , {
    name: this.opt.scoreName,
    type: 'hidden',
    required: 'required'
})
```